# How far the reproducibility can be affected by a BLAS change?

Tags: r, blas, reproducible-research

Today, I changed my BLAS to `vecLib` following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nicebread/6920c8287d7bffb03007) (I have a Mac) and the running time for the given test dropped from 34.6 to 5.6 seconds!

However, I wonder if this could affect the reproducibility of my results. Do you have any idea? On what type of operations this change will have an impact?